# Открывать приложение при переходе в сон

Tags: android

Появилась задача, "создать скринсейвер", по сути простое приложение которое должно просто на весь экран телефона постоянно транслировать одно и тоже видео (телефон все время на зарядке) и если кто то закроет приложение, что то на телефоне поклацает и оставит его, то чтоб это приложение опять запустилось.

До этого с подобными задачами вообще не сталкивался и андроид студио открыл только вчера ( , сам смог пока реализовать постоянное воспроизведение видео на весь экран устройства (то есть спрятаны все меню и т.д. и видео крутится по циклу), но столкнулся с проблемой автозапуска этого приложения если оно было свернуто (или закрыто) пользователем.

Пока нашел что можно как то справится с этим при помощи "BroadcastReceiver", но никак не пойму что с этим делать, я так понял мне нужен "POWER_SAVE_MODE_CHANGED"? Не могли бы вы подсказать как можно это реализовать или кинуть каким то примером.

С другой стороны в смартфоне есть свой скринсейвер который по дефолту открывает только изображения или "цвета", может можно как то указать ему открывать мое приложение транслирующее видео?

```xml
---activity_main.xml---

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```java
---MainActivity.java---

package com.example.screensaver;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // отключаю блокировку экрана
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        // отключаю панель навигации
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

        VideoView vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        // загрузка видео из папки
        Uri myVideoUri= Uri.parse( "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.videomob);
        vidView.setVideoURI(myVideoUri);

        vidView.start();

        // зацикливаю воспроизведение видео
        vidView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

```xml
---AndroidManifest.xml---

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.screensaver">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Fullscreen">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>
```

Comment: Может это вам нужно: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2012/12/daydream-interactive-screen-savers.html или примерно то же на русском https://habr.com/ru/post/165731/. Насколько я понял таким образом мы создаём заставку, а юзер может выбрать какую заставку и по какому событию отображать, если захочет, в настройках экрана. То есть самопроизвольно она не активируется.

Comment: @woesss благодарю! Получилось сделать, к сожалению да, придется в настройках дисплея включить "экранную заставку" и выбрать мое приложения скринсейвера, но зато это работает. 
Единственное с чем пока столкнулся, меню навигации не убирается (то есть setFullscreen(true) почему то не работает, в остальном все хорошо.